# Joomla Module rendering Clarification

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-module

I am rendering many instances of the same module type ,each time giving it a different id and parameters through code(through get module and render module). This rendering happens whenever a person visits a page. It means the modules are created then and there itself..Does this slow down the website? Please clarify.  Thanks a lot in advance..

Answer (score 0):

depends on how the cache is configured, if it's properly cached you shouldn't see a noticeable delay.

Try to put the site in debug mode and load the page, it will give you detailed times for each module.